# How to mark some grid points on netcdf map?

Tags: maps, fortran90, netcdf

I can make 2D dimensional netcdf maps of some quantity. I open it in panoply and there is color map of that quantity. But I cannot visualize some boolean value.
Can I somehow mark particular grid points with some symbol on the map (it can be diamond, square, triangle... whatever), is there a way how to do it in Fortran90? I accept also python related help. 
Again: I mean there would be color map (from real values) (which I can do) and at the same time some values will have e. g. triangle on it.

Comment: This is a programming Q/A site. There should be some code in your question. This seems like you first need to find out what you want to do with the NetCDF (in general) and only later you should care about Fortran or Python or whatever. Note that all Fortran questions should use the [tag:fortran] tag, but only after it actually contains some Fortran.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, then you can easily do that with Python and using some plotting library (e.g Matplotlib). With Fortran it is extremely tricky as it does not natively support plotting in my mind.

Basically with Python you just have to :

- read the wanted variables (coordinates and the field itself)
- make the map of the field i.e make the plot
- find the locations you want to highlight and just add those locations to the plot